# SVN deleted files, how can I recover them?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, svn, file-recovery

I use eclipse with subversion in Ubuntu linux. Today I made some new java class files and edited old one (those classes are connected). I tried to update, but there were some conflicts. So i did "update and commit" to those NEW made java files and now I can't find them anymore. They are not even in folder where my project is. How can I recover them? There were too much work made to do again
Thanks

Comment: why this files have been deleted? Does some other SVN-User deleted them via SVN _delete_ command? Try with _revert_ command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If these are really new files and you did not yet commit them there might be no chance to restore them from SVN. SVN keeps only track of commited files.

But Eclipse has a local history. You can try this one.

Just select the folder the files were in and right click, then choose "Restore from Local History"

Answer (score 2):

You could revert your changes using SVN. Theres a great article about it from Aral Balkan you can read right here: http://aralbalkan.com/1381

Shai

Comment: The problem is that there is no revision which should be my commit, so I think reverting don't help. I opened list in Eclipse where shows all revisions and there were no my commits since last (few days ago where I still hadn't made those new java files) commit.

Comment: Did you try `svn log` to check if any previous commits are available? If you don't have any other version of these files I'm not really sure i could help you ...

Comment: SVN log does show previous commits, but newest is 4 days old. It doesn't show my today commit

Comment: Im sorry but i really dont think theres anything you can do - hard for me to know when i'm not infront of your repository...

Comment: But how can SVN commit and delete my files? It should save not delete. I made "Update and commit" and they just disappeared. They should be somewhere

Comment: Well, if you did svn rm (remove) and than comitted and updated, you've actually saved the deletion, as far as i know. Maybe the files are there somewhere but I'm not sure where and how (might be encrypted somehow). Also, if you DID order svn to delete the files (even if you didn't mean to) , usually they're gone unless you've previously comitted them somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eclipse or tortoiseSVN to check out an earlier revision of the project.

I use subclipse, I think there is a revision number field somewhere in the wizard when importing a project from SVN.

Comment: How could I know which revision number I need?

Comment: You could use tortoiseSVN, right click the project and then click show log and you can see revision numbers against commits. 
Alternatively in subclipse you can right clcik the project and select team -> show history. It will have the revision numbers displayed against the changes, so just choose a revision that was one before the change in question. Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that I need those files which I created. If I revert to last revision, it won't get me back those lost files. Am I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

On windows, in Tortoise SVN the files that are deleted get moved to the recycle bin by default.  Does then linux version have a similar setting?

[image]

## however

Since your using eclipse.  This is probably a better answer
[Is there a way to recover from an accidental "svn revert"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521332/is-there-a-way-to-recover-from-an-accidental-svn-revert)

Comment: many times when executables delete files they don't go to recycle bin