# Eclipse reverts all changes to file on key press, undo not possible?

Tags: eclipse, file, save, undo, revert

Somehow I just pressed some key or key combination in eclipse (android development) and eclipse suddenly restored the previous version of the file I was working on. CTRL Z/Y does not help. Do I have to do all my changes to the file again!??

And WHAT could I have just done? I don't want that to happen anymore. How could I possible continue working with eclipse knowing this could happen again sometime.

Thanks,

Comment: That's awful. Have you already checked to see if you have any key combo mapped to "Revert" or "Revert to Saved" in Preferences->General->Keys?

Comment: Not the case. I just hope it won't happen anymore. Any way did not loose a day's worth of work, just 15 minutes or so.

Comment: I guess you can just not save it but look to the file folder to check if it is still the latest or not. I have never encounter situation like time. But you can always use a version control tool to save you.

Comment: It is **extremely** frustrating. If you accidentally hit the revert changes button in the context menu, your work is lost. The local history will not save you. Eclipse guys should change this.

Comment: You can compare with History tool.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. Typical Eclipse arrogance to not prompt before losing 45 minutes of work of precision. Sometimes I come back to my PC and bam, Eclipse forgot every edit I made. I mean: it seems to be Eclipse all by itself.

Answer (score 11):

I think I had the same problem and figured it out after a few minutes.

Eclipse keeps a local version history and it is somehow possible with a wrong click or the wrong key-press to revert back to a previous version I am not sure what caused it.

To fix it right-click on the file name and then go down to "Replace With"->"Previous from Local History"  you should now be able to find the correct version and get back your lost work.

Comment: +1, thank you, this really solves the problem, this way I managed to undo an accidental reverting process in Subversion (this way I didn't lose my modifications in some files).