# If I do a system restore, will I get my program back?

Tags: testing

I made a project on eclipse for school to hand in. I edited some minor things in my program in a rush and handed it in without checking if my program still ran. Turns out it didn't, and I can't seem to find the error. I don't have time to figure it out. if I did a system restore to that point in time before I handed it in, will my project be at the same state it was, at that time?

thank you

Sorry, I know this isn't the right section but I'm new to this site and don't know where to go...

Comment: No. System Restore only restores System files, like OS updates. What you're looking for is called Version Control, but you need to have put your project in that before you changed it. If you post your code, the “minor things”, and why you think your program didn't run we may be able to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993513/eclipse-reverts-all-changes-to-file-on-key-press-undo-not-possible in the thread it's been stated there is a 'local history' in eclipse. I can't check it right now, but you may try it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse reverts all changes to file on key press, undo not possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993513/eclipse-reverts-all-changes-to-file-on-key-press-undo-not-possible)