# Eclipse Randomly Deleting My Code when Refactoring

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse for several years now with lots of ups and downs. Recently, I started having a brand new problem: I spend 20-30 min making changes to my code and suddenly (out of nowhere) Eclipse decides to revert all the changes I worked on in the last 20-30 minutes.

<strike>I followed [the suggestion in this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220708) but Eclipse won't even show the new code I wrote in the Local History.</strike>

It's beginning to happen so frequently that it is really effecting productivity. One step ahead, two steps backwards. It occurs even when I religiously save my work every couple of minutes - even the "saved" changes are reverted.

Based on a quick analysis it seems this happens most frequently when I try to rename a variable and Eclipse says I need to select a variable (which I did, but that's besides the point) to refractor it. After I click OK in popup, at that point eclipse "undoes" all the code I worked on in the last twenty minutes or so. No questions asked.

Has anyone faced a similar situation? Really thinking of switching to IntelliJ IDEA even though I've been using eclipse for years.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**:

I noticed the issue occurs only after I get the following message:

```
A fatal error occurred while performing the refracting

A local variable deceleration or reference must be selected to activate the Refactoring
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I am now able to restore recent edits via `Local History`. In other words, the recent edits **are** showing up now in Local History, so this was an oversight on my end. However the primary problem with Eclipse reverting changes when refactoring variable **is still present**. In other words, I still need to "restore" my work every 20-30 minutes (when refactoring variable that results in fatal error message above) via `Local History`.

**UPDATE 3**:

The error also occurs when I try to refactor and get the following message:

```
Rename Refactoring: Could not a method for project handle "null" with handle identifier..
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use a plain version of Eclipse or did you install extra plugins?

Comment: @dan1st Only have a handful of plugins - Eclipse Marketplace Client 1.9.1, Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.23, Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.23, Enhanced Class Decompiler 3.22, Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna and newer) 1.5, Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna) 1.5.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a new plain java project (ideally without libraries and as minimal as possible)?

Comment: @dan1st I will try. The only theoretical explanation I can think of is that this problem surfaced after I recently started a new project and instead of creating a new project from scratch (i.e, right click -> New -> Java Project)  I duplicated a previous project (copy and pasted the project in Package Explorer) because I knew it would share a lot of code from that project. I don't know if this has anything to do with it but I have over 20 projects in Eclipse and this is the first time I am facing this kind of problem. Maybe someone who knows more than me will find this information useful.

Comment: You may try creating a backup of the project, deleting it and copying the source files from the backup.

Comment: Never seen this. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: Please show the log starting with `SESSION!` (_Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna) 1.5_ in a current Eclipse looks weird). The fact that your recent edits do not show up in the local history indicates that this is happening outside of Eclipse. Does something sync your workspace? On Windows, this can happen if you use one user profile with more than one computer.

Comment: The current maven is 1.18 "m2e - Maven integration for Eclipse". I can't find any bug reports with that message in Eclipse bugzilla.