# Get Back Reverted File Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, revert

I know this question may be similar to others, but  I could not find the solution. My SVN version is 1.8.2 I am using Visual Studio 2005 and I accidentally have reverted a file that I was working on. I watched on Recycle Bin, but could not find that file. What ways are there to get back my reverted file ? I need back not the base file, but my working copy.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No, subversion does not have a built in "revert reverted file"-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521332/is-there-a-way-to-recover-from-an-accidental-svn-revert). You could download a recovery-program and hope that the file hasn't been overwritten so you can recover it.

Comment: Is not there any other way, I Don't know, maybe SVN merge will work ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. SVN merge will merge two files, so you'll still need the "deleted" file.