# cleanup in tortoise svn removed all changes that were not committed to the repository.

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Since svn didnt allow me to commit the recent changes to the server repository by throwing 'Cleanup required' error message, I ran the clean up command. It in turn removed all the recent changes that i have made. Is there a way to bring back the files the way they were before the cleanup ?

Comment: Did you check your Recycle Bin? On my Windows 10 all reverts etc. are moved to Recycle Bin and I have to manually empty it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to recover from an accidental "svn revert"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521332/is-there-a-way-to-recover-from-an-accidental-svn-revert)