# reverting conflict resolving in SVN

Tags: linux, svn

I have had quite a lot of changes in my working copy.
Than I have updated it, because I was working on different thing, and when conflict occurred, I have mindlessly chosen option: `tf` (as I allways do). Which basically overwritten all my work that I did last week.

Is there any way, to get back that conflicted file?

This is what happened:

```
user@my-hp:~/my_directory/trunk/drivers$ svn update
Updating '.':
Authentication realm: <https://svn.something.eu:443> Company SVN Repository
Password for 'my_user': *******

U    drivers_server.py
C    drivers/printer/printer_comm_driver.py
G    drivers/printer/printer_a_driver.py
G    drivers/printer/printer_b_driver.py
U    drivers/printer/printer_driver_dummy.py
U    drivers/example/__init__.py
A    drivers/example/example/mpos_driver.py
U    drivers/example/some/driver.py
Updated to revision 3082.
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
Merge conflict discovered in file 'drivers/printer/printer_comm_driver.py'.
Select: (p) Postpone, (df) Show diff, (e) Edit file, (m) Merge,
        (s) Show all options: tf
Merge conflicts in 'drivers/pif2/pif2_comm_driver.py' marked as resolved.
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 0 remaining (and 1 already resolved)
user@my-hp:~/my_directory/trunk/drivers$
```

I want to get back `drivers/printer/printer_comm_driver.py` file, which have had conflict.

Is there any option that could save me?

Answer (score 0):

Not likely :(
If you choose "their file" you overwrite your own content. You should use `mc` = "mine-conflict" as a more sensible "default" handling, as it preserves all your changes ("their" changes are already in your repository, so no need to keep them..). But a default conflict handling procedure will never solve conflicts in a 100% way.

I personally postpone all conflict handling and review the files piece by piece so I am sure I do not lose anything.

**Last resort:**
If you have an undelete tool you may find a deleted file `printer_comm_driver.py.mine` in your filesystem (same folder as original file).

Similar question about undeleting SVN actions:
[Is there a way to recover from an accidental "svn revert"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521332/23264)